# Estimate value from curve fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to write some very basic Python code that outputs a number based on a sample of inputs and outputs. So for example if:

```
x  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 5, 10, 17, 26]

z = np.interp(7, xp, yp)
print(z)  ##expected 50, actual was 26
```

I'd like to have some way finding a best fit function that maps these values together so that I can pass it another x value and get a rough approximation of the y value. I tried reading about [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) but as far as I can tell, this isn't what I should be using because this uses a predefined function which in my case I don't have.

Note, I have no restriction on whether the function should be linear/periodic/quadratic etc because my values will vary but my assumption is that most of the functions should be linear.

I also tried [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) but I just get the last value in the `y` array for whatever `x` I input.

**EDIT:** After messing around with Cleb's answer and then comparing it with kennytm's original approach, here are my findings.[image] The most accurate technique here should be the function that is nearest to the red line. Green line represents kennytm's approach (quadratic regression was the most accurate one I tried) and the black line represents Cleb's technique (UnivariateSpline). It appears that since UnivariateSpline has no prior knowledge of the underlying model it is a little better at adapting to the values of the function which makes somewhat more accurate.

Comment: The concept that you are looking for is [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).  See, for example, the [scipy tutorial on interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) for a description of the some of the tools available in the  [`scipy.interpolate` package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

Comment: For linear interpolation of one-dimensional data, [`numpy.interp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) might be all that you need.

Comment: @warrenweckesser I dont think it is, I just tried it. Check my last edit.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `interp` doesn't do extrapolation which OP wants.

Comment: The value 7 is outside the range of the given `x` values; that is known as *extrapolation*.

Comment: So whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You could try fitting a straight line to your data by using `numpy.polyfit()` with `deg=1` or with `scipy.stats.linregress`.

Comment: If you don't care that much about the underlying model and actual parameters, I think a spline might be sufficient. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use a spline, e.g. [scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html), if you don't care about the underlying model (e.g. whether it is linear, cubic, etc) and overfitting.

Then you can just do:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [2, 5, 10, 17, 26]
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
```

To get an estimate at `x=7`, you can now simply do:

```
spl(7)
```

which returns the value you expected:

```
array(49.99999999999993)
```

This approach avoids the definition of a model.

Comment: It's not that I don't necessarily care about the model, it's just that I'm not sure. I'll try your approach and I'll compare it's accuracy to that of kennytm's answer. How accurate would you say your approach is?

Comment: @Swailem95: Not sure if one can answer your question generally; it will depend on the data you deal with. I would always plot your actual data along with the spline to see if it "makes sense". Let me know about the results of your comparisons!

Answer (score 2):

> I tried reading about `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` but as far as I can tell, this isn't what I should be using because this uses a predefined function which in my case I don't have.

Actually that function for `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` is the model you want to fit. Say you want linear regression, then you use:

```
def linear(x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

fit_params, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, xp, yp)
print(linear(7, *fit_params))
# 36.0
```

Similar for quadratic regression etc:

```
def quadratic(x, a, b, c):
    return a*x*x + b*x + c

fit_params, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(quadratic, xp, yp)
print(quadratic(7, *fit_params))
# 50.000000000004555
```

(The second return value of `curve_fit` is the covariant matrix of the output, which gives a rough picture how good the fit is)

---

If you just want to fit a polynomial with least-squares, you could just [use `numpy.polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).

```
linear_coeff = numpy.polyfit(xp, yp, deg=1)
print(numpy.polyval(linear_coeff, 7))
# 35.999999999999986

quadratic_coeff = numpy.polyfit(xp, yp, deg=2)
print(numpy.polyval(quadratic_coeff, 7))
# 50.000000000000085
```

Comment: To fit a polynomial to a data set, another option is `numpy.polyfit()`.

Comment: What if I don't know if the data is linear or quadratic? In my case I have a set of years from 1980-2014 and each year maps to a different value (power consumption) and there's not always a clear trend to the values.

Comment: @Swailem95 Well OP said "most of the functions should be linear". I think scipy is insufficient if you don't know what your data looks like.